# Google gauge with php variable not updating

Tags: javascript, php, gauge

I want to draw a simple google gauge in a page for a live windspeed meter. 
I used the google template and i replace the variable with a php variable coming from a php file which had a lot of them. 
Although the gauge is drawing with the correct value the first time it doesnt update. Here is my code.

```
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Label', 'Value'],
    ['Memory', 0],

  ]);

  var options = {
    width: 400,
    height: 120,
    redFrom: 90,
    redTo: 100,
    yellowFrom: 75,
    yellowTo: 90,
    minorTicks: 5
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);

  setInterval(function() {
    data.setValue(0, 1, <?php @include "/live/live.php"; echo $windspeed; ?>);
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }, 1000);
}
```

My live.php contains only variables as $windspeed = "15.4" etc and in auto updated with ftp exery 3 seconds. Any help is appreciated.....

Comment: When you do `include "script.php"` you're effectively copying the script as it is *right now* and putting it into your JS. That value is not being continually updated during your `setInterval`. Instead, change `live.php` to echo out the updating value and use AJAX to get that new value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I ve made another script.php that echo out the updated value but i had no clue how to use ajax and get that..

Comment: Do some googling. There's a whole lot of tutorials out there on how to use AJAX.

Comment: This is what am i doing 4 days now. I dont know ajax so i dont know what to search. Thanks for your time....

Comment: I just googled "getting started ajax". [This is the first result.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) Work through it, try out some simple examples, then you'll have it figured out.

Answer (score 1):

Your code merges the output of `/live/live.php` once, when the page is generated, presumably you want to poll this URL to get a value....

```
    ...
    setInterval(function() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
             data.setValue(0,1,xhttp.responseText);
             chart.draw(data, options);
         }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "/live/live.php", true);
      xhttp.send();   
     }, 1000);
```

In place of...

```
setInterval(function() {
    data.setValue(0, 1, <?php @include "/live/live.php"; echo $windspeed; ?>);
    chart.draw(data, options);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I also managed to getit working adding a function that calls the live.php file and get the value . setInterval(function() {
  $.ajax({
        url: '/live/live.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: php_var,
        success:function(response){
        php_var = (response);
     }
  }); 
   }, 1000);

Comment: You never mentioned jquery.

Comment: Sorry.. I m very newbie in programming... I know just a little about php and almost nothing about all other languages... Really sorry about that. Thanks again...